# ExtJS 4 : How To Reload Grid With The Same Parameter

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I wonder why ExtJS developers decide to remove `reload()` method in ExtJS 4 Store API. I think it's a bad decision.

Here is my problem. I'm using the following code to initialize a grid's store:

```
store.load({
   params: {
       paramName: dynamicParameter
   }
});
```

**NOTICE** the `dynamicParameter` variable in the code above.

Then, if I delete some records from the grid, I need to reload the store.

The problem is: the code segment which reload the store should not know the `dynamicParameter` value.

The code to delete records is like this:

```
function deleteGridItems(grid, deleteUrl){
    // get selected rows
    var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

    // ...... (codes to send request for deletion is ignored) ......

    if(success){
        grid.getStore().reload();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `grid.getStore().reload()` above will be an error because in ExtJS 4, `reload()` function doesn't exist anymore.

So how to reload the store with the same parameter??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken load() function now does exactly the same as reload() before. Try it.

you need to set proxy extra params instead specifying it each time on load():

see this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127673-Reload-Store-in-EXT-JS-4

Comment: I have tried `load()` function. But it doesn't submit  the `dynamicParameter`.

Comment: You could pass the parameter each time you call load, or it is not an option?

Comment: Thanks @innerJL for the link. But I'm a little bit unhappy with the solution. It's because I must set `store.proxy.extraParams = {paramName:dynamicParameter}` each time before loading. It's because the extraParams isn't fix, it's dynamic. And I still think that ExtJS developers' decision to remove `reload()` method in ExtJS 4 is a really bad decision.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that Ext JS doesn't appear to check before loading whether the store is already loading data. I'm not sure why this is, but it can be fixed by overriding the load() method in a `Store` or `TreeStore`.

```
load: function(options) {
    // Loading quickly will cause data in the panel to break
    if (!this.isLoading()) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
},
```

I haven't experienced issues with grids, but with trees if you press the refresh button very quickly you sometimes get an error and the tree structure breaks:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined
```